# What is the best way to get each type of probe?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

So I know there are 7 types of probes: Mining, Research, Battle, Storage, Booster, Duplicator.

What I've found so far is that Mining probes are best gotten from quests (primarily, these seem to be my rewards) and salavging Mech field items, and that you can unlock Battle probes by doing a quest at or around chapter 9 completion (via a sidequest in the hangar). Occasionally I'll also get a Research probe from salavging Mech field items as well.

I've seen that people suggest doing quests to get probes, however every time I check the quest board I don't think I've ever seen a probe as a reward. Kirsty and story quests are the only reliable source of probes that I've found so far, but by and large those appear to be Mining probes.

Is there a "best" way to get each type of probe, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a finite, set number of mining, research, storage, duplicator, and booster probes. They are in set positions on the map and are found via salvaging mechanical items.

Some storage probes can be obtained via quests (Kirsty gives a few of these for her quests) and one can be obtained by completing the Cauldros Collectopedia. It seems there are only 11 of these in total, according to the latest count.

I'm unsure of where battle probes can be regularly found. The only places I know so far are the quest that unlocks each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Mechanical spots seem to give a lot more mining probes than research. I am also wondering how to obtain more research probes.

I don't remember seeing any as random mission rewards, although I did get a few from affinity and main story missions.

Currently I have mining probes coming out of my ears xD (25+ unused and I mine more than my storage can support xD). Very few research and storage though (100k ish revenue from research, 21k storage).

Comment: One thing this doesn't touch on are the other types of probes, namely battle and storage.